# debug script that are returned as part of response on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

I have a page that load html section via `ajax` call. The response contains `html` as well as `javascript` file.

Now i am trying to find a way to put debug point on that `javascript` file.

On `IE`, I can simply search some `javascript` function that is present on that file on debugger tab and it will take me to script block containing javascript file  and i can set debug points there.

But i am not sure how can i achieve this using `chrome`.

**UPDATE**
I am returning thymeleaf fragments using ajax which include javascript file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<div th:fragment="myFrag"  th:remove="tag">

    <script  th:src="@{/js/test.js}"></script>
    //my html goes here
    </div>
```

Comment: Ajax will not execute returned content. Can you briefly describe how you execute the Javascript, please?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Thymeleaf, but from that pseudocode and the docs I [assume that `/js/test.js` would be loaded as a separate request](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#flexible-layouts-beyond-mere-fragment-insertion). If this is true, is the request made? You should see it at least in the Network panel.

Comment: yes i can see on network panel but i can't put debug point on that `js` file.

Comment: Ensure its served with 200 OK. Ensure the script is executed. Put an `alert("Hello")` into `test.js`. It should at least pop up. In the network panel the type for `test.js` shall be "script". Do you have an ad blocker running? What Chrome version is it? Try adding the script tag (without the `th:` namespace) to the index.html directly to narrow down issues with the script insertion rather than with the script itself.

Comment: i am not sure if you understand my question or not. Everything is working fine. all script are running fine. All i want is to debug `test.js` file using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug comes in with its JavaScript debugger. I'm used to using a debugger in every language I deal with, so using Firebug is a no brainer. Since it supports breakpoints, stopping execution and inspecting local variables and the rest of the scope generally beats alerts and console.logs for me.
For more details please check this link

http://beerpla.net/2009/12/17/how-to-make-firebugs-javascript-debugger-break-inside-dynamic-javascript-using-the-debugger-keyword-ie-chrome-too/

Comment: i am looking for how to do with chrome developer tools.